# function to compute sum of squares error

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I trying to teach myself Mathematica so I thought I would go through a statistics problem and compute each component individually instead of using Fit or ANOVA, etc.  Anyway ... I got stuck on how to compute the sum of squares error:

$$\text{SS}_i=\sum _{i=1}^t \left(y_{\text{ij}}^2-\left(y_{i.}\right){}^2/n_i\right)$$

I have some data

```
data = {{1, 27}, {1, 31}, {1, 26}, {1, 32}, {1, 39}, {1, 37}, {1, 
   38}, {1, 39}, {1, 30}, {1, 28}, {1, 27}, {1, 27}, {1, 34}, {2, 
   29}, {2, 28}, {2, 37}, {2, 24}, {2, 35}, {2, 40}, {2, 40}, {2, 
   31}, {2, 30}, {2, 25}, {2, 29}, {2, 25}, {2, 34}, {3, 36}, {3, 
   34}, {3, 41}, {3, 30}, {3, 44}, {3, 44}, {3, 32}, {3, 32}, {3, 
   31}, {4, 34}, {4, 34}, {4, 43}, {4, 44}, {4, 40}, {4, 47}, {4, 
   34}, {4, 31}, {4, 45}, {4, 28}, {5, 28}, {5, 28}, {5, 26}, {5, 
   35}, {5, 31}, {5, 30}, {5, 34}, {5, 34}, {5, 26}, {5, 20}, {5, 
   41}, {5, 21}, {6, 28}, {6, 26}, {6, 29}, {6, 25}, {6, 35}, {6, 
   34}, {6, 37}, {6, 28}, {6, 21}, {6, 28}, {6, 26}};
```

I group the data by using GatherBy

```
byTask = GatherBy[data, First]
```

I compute the group means and group counts

```
meansByTask = Table[{x[[1, 1]], N[Mean[x[[All, -1]]]]}, {x, byTask}]

countsByTask = Table[{x[[1, 1]], N[Length[x[[All, -1]]]]}, {x, byTask}]
```

But I don't know how to combine the parts to compute the Sum of Squares for each group.

Steve

Comment: Is `SS(i) = Sum[ y(i,j)^2 - mean[ y(i,.) ]/n(i) ]` supposed to be Mathemtica code?

Comment: no i tried to write the formula for those that didn't know what the sum of squares error formula was

Comment: So you may want to edit the question and replace it by $LaTeX$ code

Comment: \text{SS}_i=\sum _{i=1}^t \left(y_{\text{ij}}^2-\left(y_{i.}\right){}^2/n_i\right)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 6):

You probably want something like

```
byTask = GatherBy[data, First][[All, All, 2]];
Tr /@ ((# - Mean@#)^2/Length@# & /@ byTask)
(*
  {3834/169, 4690/169, 250/9, 196/5, 397/12, 2482/121}
*)
```

Comment: Thank you belisarius.  Can you explain to me what the GatherBy line does?

Comment: Never mind - figured that one out.  Thank you again!